# Java Record / Mix two audio streams

Tags: java, audio, record, audio-streaming

i have a java application that records audio from a mixer and store it on a byte array, or save it to a file.
What I need is to get audio from two mixers simultaneously, and save it to an audio file (i am trying with .wav).
The thing is that I can get the two byte arrays, but don't know how to merge them (by "merge" i don't mean concatenate). 
To be specific, it is an application that handles conversations over an USB modem and I need to record them (the streams are the voices for each talking person, already maged to record them separately).

Any clue on how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class FileMixer {

    Path path1 = Paths.get("/file1.wav");
    Path path2 = Paths.get("/file2.wav");
    byte[] byte1 = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
    byte[] byte2 = Files.readAllBytes(path2);
    byte[] out = new byte[byte1.length];

    public FileMixer() {

        byte[] byte1 = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
        byte[] byte2 = Files.readAllBytes(path2);

        for (int i=0; i<byte1.Length; i++)
            out[i] = (byte1[i] + byte2[i]) >> 1;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In a question like this, it's a good idea to show a piece of your code. In this case it *could* be for example a method which takes the two byte arrays as parameters and returns the mixed byte array, showing how you try to mix them now.

Comment: Already did it, but I get an error on the buckle, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `.Length` should be written in lowercase, so this code could not even compile. Also, what error do you get?

Comment: @GonzaloAcosta Could you provide a concise error message?

Comment: @phimuemue I'm getting: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte" but shouldn't the array index always be an int by default?

Comment: What line of code are you getting the error on?  Point it out.

Comment: It's on the for, `out[i] = (byte1[i] + byte2[i]) >> 1;`

Comment: ...You should include code that is compilable. But anyway, try this: `out[i] = (byte)(((int)byte1[i] + (int)byte2[i]) >> 1);`

Comment: @hyde it worked out with that, but now i'm getting a white noise after the mix is done. Any clue on that?

Comment: @GonzaloAcosta you need to parse/decode the wav files. They are not raw 8 bit sample blobs... Try to find a library. Or use some audio app to convert .wav files to a suitable raw files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To mix sound waves digitally, you add each corresponding data point from the two files together.

```
for (int i=0; i<source1.length; i++)
    result[i] = (source1[i] + source2[i]) >> 1;
```

In other words, you take item 0 from byte array 1, and item 0 from byte array two, add them together, and put the resulting number in item 0 of your result array.  Repeat for the remaining values.  To prevent overload, you may need to divide each resulting value by two.

Comment: Please, could you show me some piece of code as an example? I think i saw something like that around, but couldn't understand it (as you might have already seen, my java-programming skills are not at their best)

Comment: @GonzaloAcosta: Added.  The `>> 1` is a bitwise right-shift; it effectively divides the resulting number by two.

Comment: Thank you, That made things a lot more clear to me. Still can't make it work. I updated with the code I actually have, can you see what's wrong with it? thank you once again

Comment: You didn't initialize your `out` array.  Instead of `byte[] out = null` it should be `byte[] out = new byte[length];`

Comment: ♦ already corrected that, and edited the code on the question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to merge amplitude data and not just byte data. If your SampleRate is 8: one byte equals one amplitude data. But if it is 16 you need to add two bytes to one short and merge them.

Currently your loading your file like this

```
byte[] byte1 = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
```

This will also load your .wav file header into the byte array but you only want to merge actual audio data. Load it like this:

```java
public static ByteBuffer loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] sound = new byte[in.available() - 44];
        in.skipNBytes(44); // skip the header
        in.read(sound);
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(sound);
    }
```

You can then merge every byte of these Buffers or every two bytes depending on your sample size. I will use 16 as its more common.

```java
public static ByteBuffer mergeAudio(ByteBuffer smaller, ByteBuffer larger) {
        // When we merge we will get problems with LittleEndian/BigEndian
        // Actually the amplitude data is stored reverse in the .wav fille
        // When we extract the amplitude value we need to reverse it to get the actuall
        // value
        // We can then add up all the amplitude data and divide it by their amount to
        // get the mean
        // When we save the value we need to reverse it again

        // The result will have the size of the larger audio file. In my case its file2
        ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(larger.capacity());

        while (larger.hasRemaining()) {

            // getShort() for SampleSize 16bit get() for 8 bit.
            // Reverse the short because of LittleEndian/BigEndian
            short sum = Short.reverseBytes(larger.getShort());
            int matches = 1;

            // check if the smaller file still has content so it needs to merge
            if (smaller.hasRemaining()) {
                // getShort() for SampleSize 16bit get() for 8 bit

                // Reverse the short because of LittleEndian/BigEndian
                sum += Short.reverseBytes(smaller.getShort());
                matches++;
            }

            // append the mean of all merged values
            // reverse again
            result.putShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) (sum / (float) matches)));

        }

        return result;
    }
```

We now need to create our own .wav file header and append our merged data. Finally we can write the changes to the disk.

```java
public static void saveToFile(File file, byte[] audioData) throws IOException {

        int audioSize = audioData.length;
        int fileSize = audioSize + 44;

        // The stream that writes the audio file to the disk
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        // Write Header
        out.writeBytes("RIFF");// 0-4 ChunkId always RIFF
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(fileSize));// 5-8 ChunkSize always audio-length +header-length(44)
        out.writeBytes("WAVE");// 9-12 Format always WAVE
        out.writeBytes("fmt ");// 13-16 Subchunk1 ID always "fmt " with trailing whitespace
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // 17-20 Subchunk1 Size always 16
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(audioFormat));// 21-22 Audio-Format 1 for PCM PulseAudio
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(channels));// 23-24 Num-Channels 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sampleRate));// 25-28 Sample-Rate
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(byteRate));// 29-32 Byte Rate
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(blockAlign));// 33-34 Block Align
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(sampleSize));// 35-36 Bits-Per-Sample
        out.writeBytes("data");// 37-40 Subchunk2 ID always data
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(audioSize));// 41-44 Subchunk 2 Size audio-length

        out.write(audioData);// append the merged data
        out.close();// close the stream properly
    }
```

Its important that the two files you want to merge have the same
Channels,  SampleSize, SampleRate, AudioFormat
This is how you calculate the header data:

```java
private static short audioFormat = 1;
private static int sampleRate = 44100;
private static short sampleSize = 16;
private static short channels = 2;
private static short blockAlign = (short) (sampleSize * channels / 8);
private static int byteRate = sampleRate * sampleSize * channels / 8;
```

Here is your working example where I put everything together:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.ceil;
import static java.lang.Math.round;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AudioMerger {

    private short audioFormat = 1;
    private int sampleRate = 44100;
    private short sampleSize = 16;
    private short channels = 2;
    private short blockAlign = (short) (sampleSize * channels / 8);
    private int byteRate = sampleRate * sampleSize * channels / 8;
    private ByteBuffer audioBuffer;
    private ArrayList<MergeSound> sounds = new ArrayList<MergeSound>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> offsets = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void addSound(double offsetInSeconds, MergeSound sound) {

        if (sound.getAudioFormat() != audioFormat)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible AudioFormat");
        if (sound.getSampleRate() != sampleRate)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible SampleRate");
        if (sound.getSampleSize() != sampleSize)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible SampleSize");
        if (sound.getChannels() != channels)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible amount of Channels");

        int offset = secondsToByte(offsetInSeconds);
        offset = offset % 2 == 0 ? offset : offset + 1;// ensure we start at short when merging

        sounds.add(sound);
        offsets.add(secondsToByte(offsetInSeconds));
    }

    public void merge(double durationInSeconds) {
        audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(secondsToByte(durationInSeconds));

        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.size(); i++) {

            ByteBuffer buffer = sounds.get(i).getBuffer();
            int offset1 = offsets.get(i);

            // iterate over all sound data to append it
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {

                int position = offset1 + buffer.position();// the global position in audioBuffer

                // add the audio data to the vars
                short sum = Short.reverseBytes(buffer.getShort());
                int matches = 1;

                // make sure later entries dont override the previsously merged
                // continue only if theres empty audio data
                if (audioBuffer.getShort(position) == 0) {

                    // iterate over the other sounds and check if the need to be merged
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < sounds.size(); j++) {// set j to i+1 to avoid all previous
                        ByteBuffer mergeBuffer = sounds.get(j).getBuffer();
                        int mergeOffset = offsets.get(j);

                        // check if this soundfile contains data that has to be merged
                        if (position >= mergeOffset && position < mergeOffset + mergeBuffer.capacity()) {
                            sum += Short.reverseBytes(mergeBuffer.getShort(position - mergeOffset));
                            matches++;
                        }
                    }
                    // make sure to cast to float 3/1=1 BUT round(3/1f)=2 for example
                    audioBuffer.putShort(position, Short.reverseBytes((short) round(sum / (float) matches)));
                }
            }
            buffer.rewind();// So the sound can be added again
        }
    }

    private int secondsToByte(double seconds) {
        return (int) ceil(seconds * byteRate);
    }

    public void saveToFile(File file) throws IOException {

        byte[] audioData = audioBuffer.array();

        int audioSize = audioData.length;
        int fileSize = audioSize + 44;

        // The stream that writes the audio file to the disk
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        // Write Header
        out.writeBytes("RIFF");// 0-4 ChunkId always RIFF
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(fileSize));// 5-8 ChunkSize always audio-length +header-length(44)
        out.writeBytes("WAVE");// 9-12 Format always WAVE
        out.writeBytes("fmt ");// 13-16 Subchunk1 ID always "fmt " with trailing whitespace
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // 17-20 Subchunk1 Size always 16
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(audioFormat));// 21-22 Audio-Format 1 for PCM PulseAudio
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(channels));// 23-24 Num-Channels 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sampleRate));// 25-28 Sample-Rate
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(byteRate));// 29-32 Byte Rate
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(blockAlign));// 33-34 Block Align
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(sampleSize));// 35-36 Bits-Per-Sample
        out.writeBytes("data");// 37-40 Subchunk2 ID always data
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(audioSize));// 41-44 Subchunk 2 Size audio-length

        out.write(audioData);// append the merged data
        out.close();// close the stream properly
    }

}
```