# Java merge Audio files with delay and overlapping

Tags: java

My intention is **NOT** to record my system audio output or to simply merge audio files.

I need a class „AudioMerger“. It should have a method merge where the total length is given. It should then create a silent wav file of that length and add the specified sounds to it. Added sounds can overlap and there can be offset

Example:
Length of sound.wav is 3 seconds

```java
Merger merger = new Merger();
merger.add("sound.wav", 2);
merger.add("sound.wav", 6);
merger.add("sound.wav", 7);

//creates a 10 seconds wav file with the contents of sound.wav inserted at the specific seconds
merger.merge(10);
merger.saveToFile(new File("out.wav"));
```

Comment: And what did you already search for in terms of tutorials about working with audio in Java, and how did those not get you to the point where you can apply the code or ideas they show for getting this to work?

Comment: I now how to record data, I now how to play data. I now how to append empty bits to an audio array depending on my sample rate etc. I struggle the most with overlapping of two sounds. But maybe my approach of generating a bit array is  wrong? This page was helpful for example: https://www.developer.com/java/java-sound-creating-playing-and-saving-synthetic-sounds/

Comment: Then it sounds like you still want to look for how to _mix_ audio data. (There's the obvious [Java Record / Mix two audio streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453564/java-record-mix-two-audio-streams) of course, but there are tutorials about this on the web, too, generally going into a bit more detail)

Comment: I edited the question and added some code. It would be really nice if you could take a look at my problem again. My merging still sounds bad

Comment: I think the problem is that im calculating with the byte values of each index. But with 16bit sample rate 2 bytes equal one amplitude and not one. However I dont now how to fix that yet

Comment: Hmm, also why are you running over every single byte? You already know all the offsets for each insertion, iteration over each sound-associated offset would save a lot of cycles. Plus, note that you're (a) not stripping the RIFF header from your sound.wav, and (b) you're not reading in its channels/samplerate/etc to make sure your audio merger uses the same values.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion with the iterations. I did that to set default data to (byte)0 but I guess that will be the default state for every index of a byte array. What do you mean by stripping of the riff header. If I remove it from the file it wont work anymore?

Comment: You want to mix your `sound.wav` data, but you're loading the file as bytes, so you're going to get _all_ the bytes in the file: 44 bytes of RIFF header followed by actual audio data. So you want to read in the bytes, copy the sample rate, bitrate, and channel data out of the first 44 bytes of header, then remove the header.

Comment: (and you want to make sure to mix your samples properly. If your source file uses 16 or 32 bits per sample, which it almost certainly does, you need to sum-average short values, not byte values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856836/java-mixing-two-wav-files-without-introducing-noise)

Comment: And you'll probably want to use https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html so you can get and put wide values, rather than working with single bytes.

Comment: Just remember that questions with fully working code are not questions, and by definitely have to be closed as "there is nothing to fix here" =) Instead, restore your post to what it was, but post an _answer_ with your now working code, and explain all the things you had to change for future visitors. And then after you've done that, have a quick look to see how close to [my implementation of your code](https://replit.com/@Pomax/AudioMixing#Main.java) you got =)

Comment: I did so but I dont have enough reputation to close the question. What to do?

Comment: You don't: if you've restored your post, and written an answer, you've done exactly what SO is for, and folks can upvote both your post and answer if they thing it's useful, and tomorrow you can accept your own answer as "the answer that solved the problem". But do elaborate in your answer on what you had to change, and how those changes made it possible to solve the problem, so others can learn from that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the help of https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans I now have working code.

whistle.wav: https://voca.ro/1iqDr3yVZ6uG
out.wav: https://voca.ro/1jxlHkNUuH9r

The mayor problem was to create an empty wav file. To achieve this I needed to write a proper header at the beginning. You can read detailed information about the .wav header here:   http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html
When I implemented this I struggled with reading and writing bytes in Little/Big-Endian. Basically these specify the direction in which numbers are stored. Big Endian stores them like we and Java now (left to right) and Little Endian stores them reverse (right to left).   A wav file expects all its numbers to be in Little Endian. So when we load numbers from a wav file we need to convert them to Big Endian (our Java numbers) and when we write the file we need to reconvert them to Little Endian. To do so we can use the Integer.reverseBytes() and Short.reverseBytes() methods.

OneHundredTwo:
Big Endian: 102
Little Endian: 201

Another struggle I had was when merging the audio byte arrays.
I added every bit of the arrays together and calculated the mean. However my SampleSize was 16 bit so I need to calculate the mean for every two bytes and not for every.

When getting this to work first there was always a strange noise right before my inserted audio played. I carelessly filled the byte arrays with the file contents. When merging my program also merged header data and interpreted them as sound data which created this noise. After chopping off the header my audio sounded fine.

However when my streams overlapped they produced a lot of foreground noise. When calculating the mean I didnt cast my divisor to a float so it chopped of some of the audio data. 3/2 became 1 and not 1.5 rounded to two

Something I actually did correct was ensuring that my audio can only be inserted with an offset that is dividable by two. Else it would merge the first byte of the previous amplitude with the last byte of the next amplitude.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {

        AudioMerger merger = new AudioMerger();
        MergeSound sound = new MergeSound(new File("whistle.wav"));

        merger.addSound(2, sound);
        merger.addSound(5, sound);
        merger.addSound(5.5, sound);
        merger.merge(10);
        merger.saveToFile(new File("out.wav"));

    }

}
```

```java
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MergeSound {

    private short audioFormat;
    private int sampleRate;
    private short sampleSize;
    private short channels;

    private ByteBuffer buffer;

    public MergeSound(File file) throws IOException {

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        byte[] sound = new byte[in.available() - 44];

        // read header data
        in.skipNBytes(20);
        audioFormat = Short.reverseBytes(in.readShort());
        channels = Short.reverseBytes(in.readShort());
        sampleRate = Integer.reverseBytes(in.readInt());
        in.skipNBytes(6);
        sampleSize = Short.reverseBytes(in.readShort());
        in.skipNBytes(8);// make sure to cut the full header of else there will be strange noise

        in.read(sound);
        buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(sound);
    }

    public ByteBuffer getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public short getAudioFormat() {
        return audioFormat;
    }

    public void setAudioFormat(short audioFormat) {
        this.audioFormat = audioFormat;
    }

    public int getSampleRate() {
        return sampleRate;
    }

    public void setSampleRate(int sampleRate) {
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    }

    public short getSampleSize() {
        return sampleSize;
    }

    public void setSampleSize(short sampleSize) {
        this.sampleSize = sampleSize;
    }

    public short getChannels() {
        return channels;
    }

    public void setChannels(short channels) {
        this.channels = channels;
    }

}
```

```java
import static java.lang.Math.ceil;
import static java.lang.Math.round;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AudioMerger {

    private short audioFormat = 1;
    private int sampleRate = 44100;
    private short sampleSize = 16;
    private short channels = 2;
    private short blockAlign = (short) (sampleSize * channels / 8);
    private int byteRate = sampleRate * sampleSize * channels / 8;
    private ByteBuffer audioBuffer;
    private ArrayList<MergeSound> sounds = new ArrayList<MergeSound>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> offsets = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void addSound(double offsetInSeconds, MergeSound sound) {

        if (sound.getAudioFormat() != audioFormat)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible AudioFormat");
        if (sound.getSampleRate() != sampleRate)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible SampleRate");
        if (sound.getSampleSize() != sampleSize)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible SampleSize");
        if (sound.getChannels() != channels)
            new RuntimeException("Incompatible amount of Channels");

        int offset = secondsToByte(offsetInSeconds);
        offset = offset % 2 == 0 ? offset : offset + 1;// ensure we start at short when merging

        sounds.add(sound);
        offsets.add(offset);
    }

    public void merge(double durationInSeconds) {
        audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(secondsToByte(durationInSeconds));

        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.size(); i++) {

            ByteBuffer buffer = sounds.get(i).getBuffer();
            int offset1 = offsets.get(i);

            // iterate over all sound data to append it
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {

                int position = offset1 + buffer.position();// the global position in audioBuffer

                // exit if audio plays after end
                if (position >= audioBuffer.capacity())
                    return;

                // add the audio data to the vars
                short sum = Short.reverseBytes(buffer.getShort());
                int matches = 1;

                // make sure later entries dont override the previsously merged
               //continue only if theres empty audio data
                if (audioBuffer.getShort(position) == 0) {

                    // iterate over the other sounds and check if the need to be merged
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < sounds.size(); j++) {// set j to i+1 to avoid all previous
                        ByteBuffer mergeBuffer = sounds.get(j).getBuffer();
                        int mergeOffset = offsets.get(j);

                        // check if this soundfile contains data that has to be merged
                        if (position >= mergeOffset && position < mergeOffset + mergeBuffer.capacity()) {
                            sum += Short.reverseBytes(mergeBuffer.getShort(position - mergeOffset));
                            matches++;
                        }
                    }
//make sure to cast to float 3/1=1 BUT round(3/1f)=2 for example
                    audioBuffer.putShort(position, Short.reverseBytes((short) round(sum / (float) matches)));
                }
            }
            buffer.rewind();// So the sound can be added again
        }
    }

    private int secondsToByte(double seconds) {
        return (int) ceil(seconds * byteRate);
    }

    public void saveToFile(File file) throws IOException {

        byte[] audioData = audioBuffer.array();

        int audioSize = audioData.length;
        int fileSize = audioSize + 44;

        // The stream that writes the audio file to the disk
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        // Write Header
        out.writeBytes("RIFF");// 0-4 ChunkId always RIFF
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(fileSize));// 5-8 ChunkSize always audio-length +header-length(44)
        out.writeBytes("WAVE");// 9-12 Format always WAVE
        out.writeBytes("fmt ");// 13-16 Subchunk1 ID always "fmt " with trailing whitespace
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // 17-20 Subchunk1 Size always 16
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(audioFormat));// 21-22 Audio-Format 1 for PCM PulseAudio
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(channels));// 23-24 Num-Channels 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sampleRate));// 25-28 Sample-Rate
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(byteRate));// 29-32 Byte Rate
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(blockAlign));// 33-34 Block Align
        out.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(sampleSize));// 35-36 Bits-Per-Sample
        out.writeBytes("data");// 37-40 Subchunk2 ID always data
        out.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(audioSize));// 41-44 Subchunk 2 Size audio-length

        out.write(audioData);// append the merged data
        out.close();// close the stream properly
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that future visitors would benefit a lot from hearing you explain what you had to change. The links are good, but much list posts, answers should make sense even without clicking through =) (sure, a writeup is a bit of work, but it's only a one-time bit of work, which will benefit _a lot_ of future visitors).

Comment: I wrote everything I could think of. Hopefully this helps someone in the future. Thank you.

Comment: awesome, nice work!